# How to make looping 3 dimensions like that?

Tags: python, function, loops, dictionary

I try to make a mini transaction summary with code like that:

```py
price = {'mouse':10, 'hdd':60, 'rmd':23}
buying = {'mouse':3, 'hdd':2}

def total(price,buying):
    print(sum(multiple = price.values() * buying.values()))
```

output:

```
3 mouse : 30
2 hdd : 120
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate your question or what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: These are not three dimensions. You use 2 dictionaries with each "1 dimension" ( not nested)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you searching for something like this?

```
def total(price, buying):
    for item, n in buying.items():
        print(n, item, ':', n * price[item])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can choose an element from `price` and find its value from `buying` and print it.

```py
price = {'mouse':10, 'hdd':60, 'rmd':23}
buying = {'mouse':3, 'hdd':2}
def total(price,buying):
    for item in price.keys():
        #this will default to 0 if no item of this type is not sold.
        quantity = buying.get(item, 0)
        mult = price[item] * quantity
        print("{} {}: {}".format(quantity, item, mult))
```

Output:

```
2 hdd: 120
3 mouse: 30
0 rmd: 0
```